# Turn off MS SQL Server logging

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I know that it is impossible to turn off the transaction logging in Microsoft SQL Server
But my boss wants an **official** evidence about this
And I cannot find that

Please help me to find official information (preferably on MSDN) about impossibility of turning off the transaction logging in Microsoft SQL Server

Thanks

Comment: I think if you set Database's Recovery Model to Simple, you won't track transactions logs for this DataBase

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[MS KB 873235](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/873235)

End of first paragraph under "More information about transaction log files" states:

> Because the transactional integrity is considered a fundamental and intrinsic characteristic of SQL Server, logging the details of the transactions cannot be turned off in SQL Server.

I'd consider your position if your boss doesn't trust your techincal expertise and judgements

Comment: Thank you, this is that I did find

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe you can, nearest would be to use the simple recovery mode where once the transactions been successful the item is marked for deleting, ergo keeps the transaction log as near to small as possible.